# Mover imagenes asociadas a Links HTML

Tags: javascript, html5

Necesito arrastrar una imagen asociada a un `link` desde una división a otra utilizando `DRAG` and `DROP`,
la imagen se arrastra correctamente pero el enlace permanece en el mismo lugar.

El código HTML es el siguiente:

```
<div class="container" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <div id="link" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <a id="video" href="prueba2.mp4" ></a>
    </div>
    <div id="imagen" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <img id="drag1" src="iconocarpeta.ico"  width="100px" height="60px">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando arrastras tienes que definir el elemento arrastrado. Si defines el elemento arrastrado como `event.target` es la imagen. Si quiero arrastrar el elemento `<a>` utilizo `event.target.parentNode`.

Por favor lea los comentarios en mi código

```js
var elementoArrastrado;

 
  document.addEventListener("drag", function( event ) {
  //console.log("drag")
  }, false);


  document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {
    // guarda información acerca del objeto arrastrado
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)
      // guarda una referéncia del elemento arrastrado
      
      // el event.target es la imagen. Si quiero arrastrar el elemento <a> utilizo event.target.parentNode
      
      elementoArrastrado = event.target.parentNode;
      // cambia la opacidad del elemento a medio transparente
      event.target.style.opacity = .5;
  }, false);


  document.addEventListener("dragend", function( event ) {
      // reestablece el valor de la opacidad
      event.target.style.opacity = 1;
  }, false);

 
  document.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
      // previene el comportamiento por defecto del elemento arrastrado
     event.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragenter", function( event ) {
      // comprueba si el event.target es una zona de soltar  
      if ( event.target.className == "zona-de-soltar" ) {
        // y di lo és cambia el color de fondo
          event.target.style.background = "purple";
      }

  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragleave", function( event ) {
      // comprueba si el event.target es una zona de soltar  
      if ( event.target.className == "zona-de-soltar"  ) {
        // y si lo és, reestablece el valor inicial
          event.target.style.background = "";
      }
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
      // Si el elemento arrastrado es un link, este se abre en una nueve página.
      // Para que esto no pase hay que utilizar: 
      event.preventDefault();
      // comprueba si el event.target es una zona de soltar
      if ( event.target.className == "zona-de-soltar"  ) {
          // reestablece el valor inicial para el background
          event.target.style.background = "";
          // elimina el elemento arrastrado del del elemento padre
          elementoArrastrado.parentNode.removeChild( elementoArrastrado );
          // y lo agrega al elemento de destino
          event.target.appendChild( elementoArrastrado );
      }
    
  }, false);
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

#zonasDeSoltar, #arrastrables{display:flex;}  
#arrastrables div{margin:10px 17px 0 10px;}
.arrastrable {
    flex:0 0 100px;
    height: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    outline:1px solid;
    position:relative;
  }

  .zona-de-soltar {
    flex:0 0 100px;
    height: 160px;
    background: blueviolet;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:10px 10px 0 0 ;
  }

a{outline:5px solid gold; 
  height: 160px;
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div id="arrastrables">
<div class="arrastrable" draggable="true" >
  <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com"><img src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/book_blue.jpg" /></a>
</div>
  
<div class="arrastrable" draggable="true" >
    <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com"><img src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/book_white.jpg" /></a>
</div>
  
  <div class="arrastrable" draggable="true" >
    <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com"><img src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/book_orange.jpg" /></a>
</div>
  
  <div class="arrastrable" draggable="true" >
    <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com"><img src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/book_red.jpg" /></a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="zonasDeSoltar">
<div class="zona-de-soltar"></div>
<div class="zona-de-soltar"></div>
<div class="zona-de-soltar"></div>
<div class="zona-de-soltar"></div>
</div>
```